# Stripe: manage a product's quantity

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, product-quantity

I'm trying to set up a basic Stripe store to sell some t-shirts I silkscreened. I'm using [this React setup](https://github.com/ReactUniversity/038-building-an-online-store-part-3-react-router-site-layout/tree/04-top-bar-links). Each shirt has a limited quantity, about 12 of each size. I want to make it so when a size is sold out, the "add to cart" button disables.

Is there a way to track quantity with Stripe in this way? I can't seem to find any docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You client side app need to be aware of each client that buys a shirt.

There are several ways to achieve this.

- 1. The most ugly one is each `x seconds` you check all displayed t shirts on the screen quantities. aka: `setInterval(checkAvailability, x)`
- 2. When the user presses the button (still enabled) you make a call to your api to check if the related t-shirt is still available, if not, display an error message and disable the button (this is what I recommend in your case, because it's the cheapest and the simplest and can be improved in many ways).
- 3. Connect your client side app to your api using `socket` or `server side events` and each time a t-shirt is bought, you notify your client side app.